# Issue with C# WCF HTTP Operation

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, http

I am trying to get a simple WCF service to work that will process an incoming stream of data from an REST HTTP POST, I have created WCF Soap Webservices before without problem, but encountered an issue with this POST operation. I am trying to create a WCF web service that will accept an incoming POST.

I generate a new WCF project in Visual Studio, and when I test the default project that is made, using the WCF Test Client, it works without problem. However, when I do the following to try and make a WCF that accepts a POST, I get it to build correctly, I get it to start correctly without error, it says the service is added, and also it properly generates a WSDL, but when I try to post to it nothing happens. In WCF Test Client the post operation has a red x and says "This operation is not supported in the Wcf Test Client because it uses type System.IO.Stream"

the project is named WcfService1.

The file IService1.cs has the service contract:

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate="post")]
    string post(Stream input);
}
```

The file Service1.svc.cs has the method definition:

```
public string post(Stream input) 
{
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(input);
    String postdata = sr.ReadToEnd();
    sr.Dispose();

    // simple debug statement
    return "test";
}
```

I use the following html to do the post:

```
<form method="post" action="http://localhost:49163/Service1.svc/post">
    Test Data: <input type="text" name="TestField" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I found an example at http://blogs.southworks.net/erossetto/2007/09/03/raw-http-post-with-wcf/ but I am still having a problem. I am thinking it is something really simple to get this to work.

Comment: When you create a new project in WCF I think it uses basicBinding as default. Have you updated the Web.Config binding to webHttpBinding, like in the downloadable example?

Comment: OK I added a services service section to my web.config and I am trying to see if the webservice will work now, a few moments please..

Comment: In that case i'll put it as an answer :). Now you can have a REST (pun intended)

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

Update the binding method to be webHttpBinding, like in the following example

```
<services>
  <service name="SampleService" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior">
    <endpoint address=""
              behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior"
              binding="webHttpBinding"
              bindingConfiguration=""
              contract="ISampleService" />
  </service>
```